# How to pass Class instances in overload

Tags: c#, class, object

I have an array of objects (`Character`) of the Class `Player` which I instantiated in `Form1`

I need to use these objects in another form (`Combat`) but I'm not sure how to pass them though. Here is what I've tried:

```
public partial class Form1: Form
 private void combatBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form combat = new Combat(Character[0-9]);

        combat.ShowDialog();

    }

public partial class Combat : Form
  {

    Player[] character = new Player[9];

    public Combat(Player chars[0-9])
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i > 9; i++)
        {
            character[i] = chars[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the subscript `[0-9]` supposed to mean? It is not valid C#.

Comment: I'm trying to pass all 9 instances of the array. Wasn't sure how so just gave it a go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a property to `Combat` and set it from the parent form:

```
public partial class Combat : Form
{
    public Player[] Characters { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can set that property when you create the form:

```
private void combatBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Combat combat = new Combat();
    combat.Characters = somePlayerArray;

    combat.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: +1. Passing `combat` as constructor argument would match OP's code better, but this works too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to C# and would like to know why you didn't have to say Form combat = new combat(); ?

Comment: @Ralt Because we don't want to treat it like any other form; we want to access a custom property of that form that we've created.